# sql query for repeat rows

Tags: sql

```
Name       Telugu Image         price  quan
jaen123    ౭౦౦    bcb6a0b-.gif  805    23
tshirt35   ౩౫౦    9df27e4-.gif  402.5  35
jeans30-32 ౬౦౦    47d975c-.gif  690    50
jack1      ౮౦౦    4698ee8-.gif  920    25
```

I want to display this like:

```
jack1 ౮౦౦ 4698ee8-.gif 920
jack1 ౮౦౦ 4698ee8-.gif 920
jack1 ౮౦౦ 4698ee8-.gif 920
jack1 ౮౦౦ 4698ee8-.gif 920
jack1 ౮౦౦ 4698ee8-.gif 920
jack1 ౮౦౦ 4698ee8-.gif 920 means 25 times
```

Means row repeat as per the number of quantity

Comment: This seems better done in the client rather than on the database.  You need to add a tag for your specific database (MySQL/SQL Server/Oracle)

Comment: If you are using Postgres, check out the `generate_series()` function

Answer (score 1):

try to this

```
select Name,Telugu Image,price
join(
SELECT number
FROM master.dbo.spt_values where number >0  and number <=2048 group by number 
) a on a.number<=quan
```

Here limitation.It should be work on sql server and quan must be less than 2049

Comment: you can even create a numbers CTE and use that in the join